# Going from C# to Java

Tags: c#, java

I've been working with C# and more generally the .Net framework for a couple of years now. I often heard about the similarity between C# & the Java language and would like to learn more about the second one.

- Have you got any specific advice to learn Java when coming from C# ?
- Any common errors a C# programmer would do when starting Java ?
- Any documentation showing the habits you can keep and the ones you must change (still in a C# to Java optic, so something a bit more specific then a C# vs Java comparison) ?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Well, while C# and Java are superficially alike there are a number of small differences that might bite you. Generally I think the opposite direction—going from Java to C#—is less problematic. This is mainly due to C# being a more complex language so you might find many simplifications from common Java patterns but the other way around might be a little painful.

Things to look out for (partial list, not guaranteed to be exhaustive):

- Different ...

  - Naming conventions. In Java only type names start with a capital letter (i. e. PascalCase), everything else uses camelCase. Not very hard to adhere to, though.

    Also interfaces generally don't start with `I`. On the other hand you have to implement them with a different keyword. Doesn't really help in the middle of the code, though.
  - Class library :-)

    While obvious, this has been the thing I spent most time on when learning a language. When dealing with a known paradigm the syntax differences are quickly sorted out, but getting to know the standard library / class library / framework takes some time in some cases :-)
  - Patterns. Well, not quite, it's still the same stuff. But C# supports some patterns at the language level, while you still have to implement them yourself in Java. No events, but the Observer pattern (very prevalent in Swing—whenever you see a Listener, you know what to do :-))
  - Exception handling. Java has so-called *checked exceptions* which means that an exception must either be caught or declared upwards. Usually this means that you have

    ```
    catch (SomeException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    ```

    pretty often in your code<sup>1</sup> :-)
  - Types. While .NET has normal objects and value types, they both are objects and support methods, properties, &c. Java has a dichotomy of *primitive* types, such as `int`, `float`, `char`, &c. and *classes* such as `String`. Doesn't matter much since they implemented auto-boxing, but sometimes it's still annoying to wrap `int` in `Integer`.
  - Polymorphism: All Java methods are `virtual` by default whereas c# methods are not.
- Minor syntactic differences.

  - `foreach (a in b)` → `for (a : b)`
  - Different access keywords. Things like `internal` and `protected internal` don't exist. But unqualified members are visible to other classes in the same package (sort of `internal`, but then again not quite).
  - String comparison isn't done with `==` in Java. You have to use `.equals()`. While in C# `==` on strings is value equality, in Java `==` is *always* reference equality.
- No ...

  - Properties. In Java this is generally done with the `Foo getFoo()`/`void setFoo(Foo foo)` pattern which C# generates silently behind your back when using properties but you have to do it explicitly in Java. Generally, to keep the language itself simpler many things in Java are just conventions. Still, most of the time you're better off adhering to them :-)
  - Operator overloading. Deemed a hazard to the righteous programmer they weren't implemented for fear of abuse. Don't need them too often anyway, not even in C#, but sometimes they are nice and then you're missing something.
  - Indexers. You always have to access list items through `myList.get(5)` instead of the array-like syntax `myList[5]`. Just a mild inconvenience, though.
  - LINQ (though there exist implementations<sup>2</sup> but it's not as nicely integrated), or lambda functions<sup>3</sup> (no delegates anyway, but anonymous classes), extension methods, or partial classes (yes, that's a painful one when dealing with Swing, unless you're *very* disciplined), and a few more things.
  - Multidimensional arrays. You can use jagged arrays (arrays of arrays), buttrue multidimensionality isn't there.
- Generics are compile-time only, at runtime only `Object`s remain. Also wildcards in generics can be hard to resolve sometimes when the compiler complains about all of the four `?` in your generics having different types. (Though to be fair: That was a case where I would have needed type information at runtime anyway so I reverted back to `Object`s).

*General advice:* Grab a friend with Java experience and let him glance over your code. While he probably can't tell you everything you should take care of when you directly ask him that question, he can spot strange things in code just fine and notify you of that. This has greatly helped me learning Java (although I learned Java first and then C#, so it might be different).

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, I know many catch blocks look different, but still, this is probably the archetypical one and [not even that rare](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2009/09/checked-exceptions-i-love-you-but-you.html).
<sup>2</sup> [Quaere](http://xircles.codehaus.org/projects/quaere), [JaQue](http://code.google.com/p/jaque/), [JaQu](http://h2database.com/html/jaqu.html), [Querydsl](http://source.mysema.com/display/querydsl/Querydsl)
<sup>3</sup> There's [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/), though. Thanks for pointing that out, [Esko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44523/esko).

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: While there isn't "true" lambda functions in Java, there's LambdaJ: http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/

Comment: in c# == between strings is actually object comparison: if you compare (object)"aa" == "aa" you'll not necessarily get a true, hence why you should use .equals in c# too :)

Comment: @Ed: Well, `==` in C# is still overloaded to be value equality. Sure, if not both operands are strings then that won't work. Comparing a string variable with a literal string, however, should pose no surprises.

Comment: Are there also differences in inheritance and/or interface implementation (what or how many)?

Comment: @johannes sorry, I probably explained that badly: if you compare a string that is currently viewed as an object (due to being passed as an object from a function, for example), with another identical string that is currently a string, it will not compare the string values but instead do object comparison, and not necessarily return true.

Comment: @Ed: Right you are. This is a pitfall, agreed. And I think Eric Lippert had a blog post about that, too. Still, the compiler warns about it so I think while it might be harmful it shouldn't cause much grief in practice.

Comment: @Johannes: hmm, I've not seen compiler warnings about it, it was actually ReSharper that tipped me off on that one ;) I've only seen it cause issues a couple of times, and they were all in completely dynamic environments where someone slipped up, so I guess it's not the end of the world. Worth knowing though!

Comment: @Jay: All methods are virtual by default, as noted by Florian Doyon below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109807/going-from-c-to-java/2110211#2110211 – missed that one.

Comment: Java's `final` is equivalent to C#'s `readonly`, **not `const`**!

Comment: Hm. I was coming from C# to Java here. And in that respect you'd have `final` as a replacement for both `const` and `readonly`, actually. At least for fields. Removed, though.

Comment: Regarding generics "only Objects remain" is not *entirely* true. It is reduced to the lower bound, which often happens to be `Object` but could be a different one as well (for example if you use `<T extends Number>`, then the lower bound will be `Number`).

Answer (score 15):

I honestly think the biggest hurdle for many C# developers trying to learn Java is learning a new IDE. Visual Studio is great, and when you're coding in C# for a long period of time, you get used to it. When having to move over to Eclipse or Netbeans, you suddenly feel lost. How do I set a breakpoint? Where's the immediate window? How do I create a windows app? etc etc... I know this sounds crazy, but I'm telling you, people get very attached to their IDE's and have a tough time getting used to new ones...

Comment: The same is true for the other direction, too :-). Though Eclipse people usually complain about the refactoring in VS sucking :-)

Comment: I don't find it hard moving between Eclipse/VS, even when using several languages... C++, C#, Java, Flex...

Comment: @John: No, it's not **hard** to do, it's just intimidating at first.

Comment: @Johannes. You probably already know about Resharper, but if not then check it out. Refactoring in VS does suck without it. :)

Comment: @mrp: Have used it briefly, but it comes with a price tag I wasn't willing to bear for what little I'm doing at the moment with VS. At work we didn't have it either. And currently I'm back to Eclipse (for Java) and a text editor (for everything else) ;-). I found that Resharper was a little overzealous in suggesting fixes for your code, though. I don't really want to re-write *every* delegate as a lambda expression just because I can.

Comment: Not just the IDE, but the java development environment in general. And I don't think I ever started a new c# project from a template that wouldn't run out of the box D: so spoiled and lost...

Answer (score 10):

Languages themselves are pretty similar, sans few keywords and Java lacking some features C# programmers got used to (properties, `using`, reified (non-type-erased) generics).

The main problem here is knowledge of frameworks, of which there are thousands for Java.

Comment: +1 for mentioning frameworks. The Java language is quite compact (how many keywords?) but the frameworks you might have to learn are big and sometimes cumbersome eg J2EE

Answer (score 5):

The main language is fine. Getting to know the libraries will be one thing which takes time. If you're doing web-applications, there is a LOT to learn... equivalent technologies to WCF and ASP.net.
You don't say what kind of area you work in... desktop, server, or web-server?

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to say. As a Java programmer learning C#, the language is easy (and mostly the same), its navigating and learning the libraries, while having to get used to a different IDE, that is hard.

Answer (score 3):

Biggest difference between C# and Java : In Java, all methods are `virtual`. Hence the reason why tools such as NUnit and such came from the Java world.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, if you're a competent C# programmer I don't believe there's much you do need to know apart from packaging and deployment of applications.

Here's a good link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C_Sharp

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing you need to learn is how to Greenspun C#'s functional style features in Java.  For example, you can expect to make a lot of interfaces with only one method to get around Java's lack of lambda functions and delegates.

Comment: I think I fear this the most D:

Answer (score 1):

I honestly recommend [Java in a Nutshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109807/going-from-c-to-java). Most Java/any_other_lang introduction books are for totally novice readers explaining the concept of a loop for pages and recursion for a chapter... You can start writing Java programs within two days with this book. Of course it will take you a long time to understand what is going on under the hood and how to use all the available framework. But once the language itself is mastered, it is easy to get along even with google only resources.

Answer (score 1):

I made a transition from Java to C# and back to Java again. I think syntactically they are very similar and most of the trouble I had was learning the .NET APIs and learning how to use them effectively. Many times I was using 'syntactic sugar', writing my code as if it was in Java and then translating it to C#. I spent a lot of time on Microsoft's website reading and learning about the APIs which was a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

Although, this is the other way around, I found the following link to be quite useful for comparing Java and C#.

[C# From a Java Developer's Perspective](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html)