# Java for Software Developers

Tags: java, development-environment

I am a .NET developer (and have been for a while now). I work for an organization that was just recently acquired by a larger company whose primary development language is Java. There are a few .NET developers, but the ratio of .NET to Java has decreased substantially now that the teams have merged.

That being said, I've decided it would be best for me to start Java development. However, most of the books I've seen so far for "learning Java" all take a very basic approach (what is a class, OOP principles, etc etc). I am comfortable with this part of development and don't need a primer (unless there are differences so profound that someone recommends the fundamentals from a Java perspective...).

Anyway, I'm looking for a book recommendation for Java development from a software developer's perspective that discusses today's techniques. For example, MVC architecture, application best practices (I am a web developer, this includes web services), is it worthwhile to work with JSPs or consider Ruby instead, etc etc.

A HUGE bonus would be "learning through doing". Something like Murachs, where I can step through a project from start to finish, and is light enough on fundamentals that I don't get bored. I'm hoping to walk away with enough basic knowledge to volunteer for some internal projects and grow from there.

I'm sorry if my question is needlessly broad, but I'm struggling to find a starting point aside from my Eclipse installation (I am doing this on Ubuntu, deliberately avoiding Windows).

Thanks for any direction or insight you can offer.

EDIT - After discussing with a co-worker, and reading Bert's great suggestion (all of them have been excellent, thank you all very much), it turns out the main focus is on EE, and Glassfish. They use NetBeans for development, since it is tightly bound to Glassfish.

This doesn't mean much to me, except that I think the parallel drawn is IIS/Web apps to Win32 apps. But perhaps it will help clarify some of the more open-ended questions in my OP.

Comment: With .NET, did you primarily write web apps, or desktop applications? Did you use C# as the language?

Comment: Sorry yes - my background is in C#.

Comment: similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820437/life-after-head-first-java/3820449#3820449

Comment: Since you have a C# background you might find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109807/going-from-c-to-java) interesting

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html) By Josh Bloch

It may not be "learning by doing" but it gets into the details of how to use the Java language effectively.

I would then complement it with [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) by Josh Bloch and Neal Gafter

Comment: +1: this is one book every serious Java developer should read.

Comment: good idea, he will be lost in Java. Java and C# are not like C++ and C, but like Ruby and CSS. He should learn what is a class, OOP principles, etc etc.

Comment: @01: He said he already understands C#, and specifically asked for materials that skip the basics and move on to the interesting points.

Answer (score 3):

My best bet is to learn Spring based on your requirements:

> MVC architecture, application best
>   practices (I am a web developer, this
>   includes web services), is it
>   worthwhile to work with JSPs or
>   consider Ruby instead, etc etc.

You can start by visiting SpringSource at http://www.springsource.org/

Comment: I'd say Spring is a bit overkill if OP hasn't got a solid grasp of "pure" Java for starters.

Comment: +1, except can be either Spring or EJB3, depending on whether he's going to get to use an application server that supports EJB3.

Comment: he knows C#, do you guys really don't know what C# is? Is like Java++, so he should know what a class is and OOP principles, etc etc. I use Java and I learn C# in a few days.

Comment: @01, that's why he should start learning Spring :) It expects you know OOP and what classes are; otherwise, it would be difficult to learn

Answer (score 2):

There are a few points I would like to make to you:

- The basic Java *language* is rather small and C-ish.  To my understanding C# and Java works almost identically here.
- The Java *runtime library* is VERY, VERY BIG, and rather unlike C#.  Very few people know *all* of the Java 6 runtime library well.
- There are several IDE's in common use for Java.  You will want to learn the one used by the rest of the team.

I would suggest having a brisk walk through the Oracle Java Tutorial, just to get the hang of the spirit and do some of the exercises, and then look at the common "Java for C# programmer" cheat sheets on the internet.  Then do a lot of code, and then read Effective Java.

(For those who think they know Java 6 runtime well, please consider if you are familiar with RMI, the Rhino Javascript engine, and XPath in the XSLT implementation and all the rest)

Comment: Well, i've used RMI, including over IIOP with a C++ client (horrific!), written a serialized object parser (serialization is part of RMI, right?), debugged javascript running in Rhino by stepping though the interpreter inner loop, and i use XPath every day. But XSLT ... dang it, i knew i was missing something!

Comment: @Tom, care to explain how you use XPath outside of XSLT?

Comment: ørn: the classes in javax.xml.xpath can be applied to DOM objects. In my case, this is set up by HtmlUnit, and we use it to make queries on web pages that HtmlUnit has loaded, for testing - things like "assert that there is exactly one element matching //div[@id='shoppingCartInfo']".

Comment: @Tom, thanks for explaining.  I've only ever used XPath inside XSLT scripts, so it is nice to know that it is usable elsewhere too.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby makes no sense unless you're writing JRuby on the JVM.

If you're writing web apps, you'll need to know JSPs written using JSTL (JSP standard tag library), servlets, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  Download Tomcat from Apache - it's a servlet/JSP engine that will let you deploy web apps locally for learning.  It has an HTTP listener built in, so you don't need IIS or Apache.

You'll need to know how to create and deploy a web archive (WAR) file.  That's a ZIP file that contains the standard format for a web application.

I'd have a look at the Tomcat "first web app" docs to get a feel for it.

Once you have that, come back and talk about frameworks.  (When you do, I'll recommend Spring.)

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the following thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far

Comment: Thanks for this. The Java Puzzlers book looks really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some references I like.  I'm sure there are better, but there are the ones I have read and can vouch for:

[Java in a Nutshell](http://books.google.com/books?id=mvzgNSmHEUAC&pg=PT23&lpg=PT23&dq=Java+in+a+Nutshell+google+books&source=bl&ots=3n03nsipvU&sig=41Vlu4kuwh9HY7XY_oXFOhG6V5Y&hl=en&ei=BQESTf71FsOBlAf5rsTqCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a classic summary of the core language.  If you need more, there are books like [Java for Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137001290) for programmers transitioning to Java (I have *not* read it).

[Sun's Core Servlets and JavaServer Pages](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaserverpages/cservletsjsp/index.html) was a good book for Java servlets and JSPs.  But consider that a lot of web tech is built on top of this (e.g. Spring), so this may be giving you foundation but not direct knowledge of the specific framework you will be using.  Also a lot of web tech these days are client-side/JavaScript/AJAX-based, e.g. jQuery.

As for MVC, consider focusing on MVP instead.  I been playing around with [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/index.html) to leverage my Java background to create client-side apps, but it is also a good way to get some idea of MVP - read *Large scale application development and MVP* [*Part I*](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html) and [*Part II*](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html), and the [*GWT MVP Development with Activities and Places*](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).  However, GWT keeps evolving.

My last suggestion is that you narrow your focus - try to figure out what frameworks are popular at work and decide if you want to focus on a tier: front (e.g. HTML/CSS/jQuery), middle (e.g. Spring), or back-end (e.g. Hibernate).  Once you figure this out, then post a more specific question(s) (e.g. what are the best resources for learning XYZ).

Answer (score 0):

Just from my experiences with java (limited but I took a Web Dev course teaching JSP's) Any decent technology for it is usually 3rd party. However, from what I can tell when doing web dev I would use Netbeans, Netbeans has Tomcat built in especially in Ubuntu for easy debugging.

Answer (score 0):

More on similar lines you can find answers from this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820437/life-after-head-first-java/3820449#3820449

Answer (score 0):

The Java landscape is quite wide as you probably have already figured out.

There are hundreds of frameworks and tools that can be used for basically doing the same thing. To get an idea, you can take a look at [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/mraible/comparing-jvm-web-frameworks) written by Matt Raible, where he compares a number of Java web frameworks.

As someone else suggested, you should definitively take a look at the Spring Framework. It is widely used in the enterprise world. There are several good books about Spring. 
If you want to get the basics of Spring MVC in a "tutorialized" style, you can take a look at this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059584X). It doesn't cover the latest Spring version (3.0) and it is not a "perfect" book, but it should allow you to get the basics while running some examples.
Also, there are literally thousand of Spring-MVC tutorials on the web.
For instance, you can take a look at:
http://www.adobocode.com/spring/a-spring-web-mvc-tutorial

RESTful services are also quite popular these days. I have been working with the [Resteasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) framework from JBoss and I found it very easy to setup and work with. This [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596158057) explains the REST architecture and uses Resteasy as framework for the examples.

I also recommended "[Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126)" from O'Reilly. It covers the most important patterns using Java and it will help you to see how the language can be used for  patterns you may be already familiar with.

One more suggestion: you may considering "tuning in" on [Java TV](http://www.java-tv.com/). It's a great resource with hundreds of Java tutorial videos. It covers a wide spectrum of technologies so you should be able to find something for you.